# Is it safe to remove the craft/storage/runtime/sessions folder?

Tags: session, storage

I'm unable to transfer a site over to my development server because I keep getting problems with disk space. Space is actually fine, it's the number of inodes being used up. Using cPanel I get an error when using file manager to view the sessions folder, so I think that's the issue.

Using the following command, which I think is the one for counting the number of files in a directory:

```
ls | wc -l
```

It looks like there are over 300,000 files in there. How safe is it to delete the entire directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/folder-structure#craft-storage)

> runtime/ – Pretty much everything in here is there for caching and logging purposes. Nothing that Craft couldn’t live without, if the folder happened to get deleted.

It is safe to delete it

Comment: Thanks. I felt as much but is always good to get a second opinion! Doing this reduced the server's inode usage from 30% to 5% and allowed me to transfer it across to my (smaller) dev server.